# Cannot add-wants a service to a device even though the device is listed and status is queryable

Tags: linux, debian, systemd, administration, midi

The [LPD8](https://d1jtxvnvoxswj8.cloudfront.net/wysiwyg/akai-pro/pdp/lpd-8/9bbc3e054ec5cfcb0f37d691ebf901f4.jpg) is a music physical hardware. When plugged, I would like it to start the [Fluidsynth synthesizer](https://www.fluidsynth.org/). On Debian, there is a `fluidsynth.service` that runs an `--user` instance of the synth.

Systemd is aware of the device after it was plugged:

```
$ systemctl --user list-units --type=device

UNIT                                                                                                LOAD   ACTIVE         DESCRIPTION
...
sys-devices-platform-soc-1c1a000.usb-usb1-1\x2d1-1\x2d1.3-1\x2d1.3:1.0-sound-card1-controlC1.device loaded active plugged LPD8
...
```

I can query the status of the LPD8 both in description and unit forms:

```
$ systemctl status LPD8.device

○ LPD8.device - /LPD8
     Loaded: loaded
     Active: inactive (dead)


$ systemctl status sys-devices-platform-soc-1c1a000.usb-usb1-1\x2d1-1\x2d1.3-1\x2d1.3:1.0-sound-card1-controlC1.device

○ sys-devices-platform-soc-1c1a000.usb-usb1-1x2d1-1x2d1.3-1x2d1.3:1.0-sound-card1-controlC1.device - /sys/devices/platform/soc/1c1a000.usb/usb1/1x2d1/1x2d1.3/1x2d1.3:1.0/sound/card1/controlC1
     Loaded: loaded
     Active: inactive (dead)
```

However, I can't `add-wants` the `fluidsynth.service` to the LPD8 device: systemd seems to complain about a missing device file.

```
$ systemctl --user add-wants LPD8.device fluidsynth.service
Failed to add dependency: Unit file LPD8.device does not exist.

$ systemctl --user add-wants sys-devices-platform-soc-1c1a000.usb-usb1-1\x2d1-1\x2d1.3-1\x2d1.3:1.0-sound-card1-controlC1.device fluidsynth.service
Failed to add dependency: Unit file sys-devices-platform-soc-1c1a000.usb-usb1-1x2d1-1x2d1.3-1x2d1.3:1.0-sound-card1-controlC1.device does not exist.
```

What do I miss to be able to start a `fluidsynth.service` whenever the LPD8 is plugged in ?

Comment: Device is not a unit.
https://superuser.com/questions/851846/how-to-write-a-systemd-service-that-depends-on-a-device-being-present